# How do I mark each word in a string that is longer than 4 characters in Javascript

Tags: javascript, join, split, character

My duty: **I get a string from the database and have to highlight every word that is longer than 4 characters in bold.**

I just don't know how to split the string meaningfully so that all special characters are respected.

1. If I share the code with `split(" ")`, individual words are put together like: `"World,<br/>it's"`.
2. If I split the code with `split(",")` or regex, I cannot join the string again with `join(" ")` because the necessary characters have been removed.

Here is my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Tenarius/59b7gkeL/27/

Thanks a lot

Comment: Write a regex to get your array of strings on which you can do foreach and make them bold

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [String#replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with a regex to wrapp all words that are 4 characters or longer in a `<strong>` tag.

the regular expression matches a word-boundary followed by at least 4 characters `a-z` followed by another word boundary.

```js
const text = "Hey World,<br/>it´s a (very) fine day!<br/><br/>Some Greets!";

document.querySelector("#out").innerHTML = text.replace(/\b[a-z]{4,}\b/gi, "<strong>$&</strong>");
```

```html
<div id="out"></div>
```

This solution will work for very very very simple pieces of markup like in your example, but reular expressions are not good to parse HTML *(neither is your approach with splitting)*.

You'd rather want to traverse the DOM and check the content of every `#text`-node and replace it accordingly.

Comment: For this example, this is a perfect and simple solution. Impressive!

Answer (score 2):

You can use regex :

https://regex101.com/r/NcAoDv/1

```
const regex = /[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,}/g;
const str = `Hey World,
it´s a (very) fine day!

Some Greets!`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```